# Question about the limit of the product of two sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Lets suppose $a_n$ and $b_n$ denote two sequences.

Then does the following statement always hold?

$
\lim_{n \to \infty}(a_n+b_n)=a \land 
\lim_{n \to \infty}(a_n-b_n)=b \Rightarrow 
\lim_{n \to \infty}(a_n \cdot b_n)=\frac{a^2-b^2}4 
$

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** It follows from your assumptions that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\frac{a+b}2$ and that $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=\frac{a-b}2$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$a_nb_n = \frac14 \left[(a_n+b_n)^2 - (a_n-b_n)^2\right] \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} \frac14 (a^2 - b^2)$$